# A problem about federated tables in different clusters

Tags: mariadb, galera, federated-table, federated-storage-engine

I have a Mysql server(node A) in galera cluster 1 and a Mysql server (node B) in galera cluster 2.
Node A and node B are indifferent cluster so they have completely different write nodes.

I'm trying to join tables in node A with those tables in node B use FederatedX engine.
But found these words in MariaDB's Knowledge Base about the FederatedX's limitations.

> There is no way for the handler to know if the foreign database or table has changed. The reason for this is that this database has to work like a data file that would never be written to by anything other  than the database. The integrity of the data in the local table could be breached if there was any change to the foreign database.

These nodes are in different clusters,so it must be update by other write nodes.
But I need to figure out the way to join Tables in different nodes.

Some website says that federated tables will use remote server's data.
It sounds like that I don't have to worry about it... But I'mnot quite sure.

So...my question is...Does Federated tables in different clusters will work?

Thanks a lot.